API & Middleware Problem, can't reach /api/auth/providers
i'm following a tutorial  about Next Auth V5
i'm trying my best to follow but i'm a beginner at coding,timestamp of where i'm stuck is 2:09:45 / 8:00:56
on the Middleware & Login part, my problem is that i can't reach "localhost:3000//api/auth/providers"
//route.ts

import { handlers } from "@/auth";
export const { GET, POST } = handlers;

//./auth.ts:

import NextAuth from "next-auth";
import GitHub from "next-auth/providers/github";
import Google from "next-auth/providers/google";

export const { auth, handlers, signIn, signOut } = NextAuth({
  providers: [GitHub, Google],
});

//app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/route.ts:

import { handlers } from "@/auth"
export const { GET, POST } = handlers

i didn't try anything because i don't understand anything lol

I think the url is wrong. Did you try http://localhost:3000/api/auth/providers ?

idk if i wrote it the wrong way but now that i tried with yours it gives me the same error

i deleted all the middleware part and refollowed again the video to see if i didn't do anything wrong but seems like the error is caused by something else

I can't seem to help you out with the info you provided. I need to know how you are calling the function and how you implemented the code. Also it would be apprecited if you could share the error message

i can share the code to you if you want, i stopped working on this project since i'm just starting to code so i can't fix these problems when they happen even though i'm following a tutorial on youtube, anyway NextAuth v5 is way to complex for me so if you can help i won't say no and i'll provide anything you need on the code to help you understand my problem
